# CSS animation isn't working until click on Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I was trying to build a auto sliding bar from right to left with an array of data in Angular. Currrently, the animation wasn't working until user click on it. I tried changedetectorref, setTimeout() and trigger click event manually, but nothing work. Please help me on solving this.

The observation is that the data fetched from backend are received and shown (`this.offer` has its correct value) but the animation is paused. After several seconds, the shown data disappears by itself. When user click the blank sliding bar, the function of clicking on a data triggers and the animation starts. Please let me know if any further information is required.

HTML Part

```
    <div class="ticker-wrap bg-black">
        <div class="ticker py-2.5" id="bar-part-1">
            <a class="ticker__item" [id]="'talent-' + o.uniqueCode" [href]="'/talent/' + o.uniqueCode" (click)="openTalentDetailDialog(o.uniqueCode)"
                *ngFor="let o of offers">
                <div class="flex-col content">
                    <strong>{{o.uniqueCode}}</strong>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ticker py-2.5" id="bar-part-2">
            <a class="ticker__item" [href]="'/talent/' + o.uniqueCode" (click)="openTalentDetailDialog(o.uniqueCode)"
                *ngFor="let o of offers">
                <div class="flex-col content">
                    <strong>{{o.uniqueCode}}</strong>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Part

```
$duration: 40s;

@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes ticker {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

.ticker-wrap {

    // position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    // bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    // height: 4rem;
    // padding-left: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 64px;

    .ticker {

        // display: inline-block;
        display: inline-flex;
        // height: 4rem;
        // line-height: 4rem;
        // white-space: nowrap;
        // padding-right: 100%;
        box-sizing: content-box;

        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
        animation-name: ticker;
        -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
        animation-duration: $duration;

        &__item {

            display: inline-block;

            padding: 0 2rem;
            // font-size: 2rem;
            color: white;

            cursor: pointer;

            .content {
                max-width: 450px;
                min-width: 450px;
                white-space: pre-wrap;
            }

            &:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

        }

    }

    &:hover {
        .ticker {
            animation-play-state: paused;
        }
    }
}
```

TypeScript part

```
    loadRecentOffers() {
        console.log('loadRecentOffer is triggered');

        this._businessService.getRecentOffers().subscribe(async o => {
            console.log('recent offers: ', o);
            await Promise.all(o.map(oo => {
                oo.time = moment(new Date(oo.createdAt)).fromNow();
            }));
            this.offers = o;

            // this._matSnackBar.open('offer applied', 'Close');
            setTimeout(() => {
                this._cdr.markForCheck();
                this._cdr.detectChanges();
                // this._matSnackBar.open('cdr triggered', 'Close');
            }, 100)
        })
    }
```